# How to create a bar graph from echarts using JSON data?

Tags: angularjs, bar-chart, echarts, apache-echarts

I want to create a bar graph from JSON data which looks like:

```
[
   {
      "amount":0,
      "country":"Australia",
      "year":"2014"
   },
   {
      "amount":20,
      "country":"UK",
      "year":"2011"
   },
   {
      "amount":10,
      "country":"Australia",
      "year":"2014"
   },
   {
      "amount":43,
      "country":"UK",
      "year":"2014"
   }
]
```

The country will be on the x-axis and the count of the country will be on the y-axis. How do I do this using `echarts`?